# how to delete a partition(sdb6) that is ordered before the root partition (sdb7)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mount

Recently I has been struggling with updating from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 2.04, and I ended up installing a new os. now I have my old root partition as /dev/sdb6, and I formatted it, and I want to use it to extend the current root partition (/dev/sdb7). but it's hard as it's before the current root in order. Any help how can I do this ? [image]

[image]

Comment: The last line is where you will have problems(maybe major).  If you can have a picture from gparted, it might us a better idea.  Any partition work will probably have to done from a live ubuntu USB.  Backing up first is a very good idea, if any important data involved.  If no data, might just be easier to install again, but use gparted to make partitions the way you want.

Comment: let's say I booted into a live usb and deleted sdb6, the current root which is sdb7, would be assigned as sdb6, but then os would be corrupted cause all the system reads the  root as sdb7 not sdb6 right?

Comment: sd(x) is assigned at boot up.  You do not want to depend on it, if deleting something, it can and does change.  If deleting old root(make sure and double check), should only need to do update-grub before shutting down.

Comment: Even with deleting old root, depending where it is placed on disk,adding space to new root might be difficult.  Sometimes it is a lot easier to start over and make partitions before installing.  A gparted picture would help in showing what is in the way.  It is too easy to goof this stuff up and loose all data that is important to you.

Comment: If no data I would delete sdb5,sdb6 and sdb7 and reinstall as one partition of ~100GBs,   Do not need swap partition anymore.

Comment: You should only have one ESP - efi sytem partition per drive. And should be using gpt, not MBR(msdos) which you have if you have an extended partition.

Comment: @crip659, I have attached a pic of the gparted, I literally have been spending the last three days fixing issues, till I finally reached this dual boot again, all the data I can move to the other hdd, but I just dont wanna start from scratch again building configuration, if I take a snapshot with timeshift, would I be able to restore all my configuration after a new os ?

Comment: @oldfred I have dual boot, sdb1 is my windows loader. and I am now experienced with gpt abd MBR tbh

Comment: That picture is almost perfect for what you want to do.  Everything in right place.  Oldfred can probably tell how to delete swap partition safely(or google), and then just add sdb5 and sdb7 to sdb6.  A lot of these questions usually have very important partition that can't be moved in the way.

Comment: I came across how to delete the swap, but then how would I simply add sdb7( the root) to sdb6, and would't that mess with system?

Comment: Delete sdb5 and sdb7 and then add space to sdb6.  Might need to install boot repair on the USB to fix grub.  Just make sure to double and triple check everything first.